# Extracting data with Headless Selenium browser with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a way to extract the GA datalayer object from a website with a headless browser via Python so therefore; I've follow the instructions from [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/)
and...

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.example.com/")
# DL = currentURL.dataLayer 
# Do something with DL
```

What is the keyword I'm looking for here? `driver.something` should give me the dataLayer object. As a reminder: dataLayer object is a javascript object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, from what I understand, `dataLayer` is a global variable, use [`execute_script()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script):

```
driver.execute_script("return dataLayer;")
```

Note, that you may need to [explicitly wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the page to load before executing the script.

Or, at least, increase the [page load timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout):

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```